# Homogenization of Morse-Bott functions

Tags: differential-topology, vector-bundles, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a compact manifold of dimension $n$.
A smooth function $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ is called **Morse-Bott** if the set critical points of $f$ is a disjoint union of compact submanifolds $C_1,\ldots,C_k$ and

> (1) for each critical point $x\in C_i$ the Hessian of $f$ in the transversal direction to $C_i$ is non-degenerate.

A well known analogue of Morse lemma, see e.g. [the paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0723-0869(04)80014-8) by A. Banyaga and D. E. Hurtubise, claims that the above condition (1) is equivalent to the following one:

> (2) Suppose $\dim C_i = k < n$.
> Then for every $x\in C_i$ there are local coordinates $(u_1,\ldots,u_k, v_1,\ldots,v_{\lambda}, v_{\lambda+1},\ldots, v_{n-k})$ such that
> $$  f(u_1,\ldots,u_k, v_1,\ldots,v_{\lambda}, v_{\lambda+1},\ldots, v_{n-k}) = -\sum_{i=1}^{\lambda} v_i^2 + \sum_{i=\lambda+1}^{n-k} v_i^2. $$

One can regard the above property (2) as follows.
First recall that a **regular neighborhood** of a submanifold $C \subset M$ is a smooth retraction $p:E \to C$ of an open neighborhood $E$ of $C$ in $M$ together with a structure of a vector bundle for $p$.

Also, let $p:E\to C$ be a vector bundle, and $m\geq2$ be a natural number.
Then a smooth function $g:E \to\mathbb{R}$ will be called **$m$-homogeneous** if $g(tx) = t^m g(x)$ for all $x\in E$ and $t\in [0;+\infty)$.

Now consider the trivial vector bundle
$$p:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{k}, 
\qquad p(u_1,\ldots,u_k, v_1,\ldots,v_{n-k}) = (u_1,\ldots,u_{k}).$$
Then (2) can be reformulated as follows:

> (3) for every point $x\in C_i$ there exists an embedding $q:\mathbb{R}^n\to M$ such that $q^{-1}(C_i) = \mathbb{R}^k\times 0^{n-k}$, and the composition $f\circ q:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ coincides near $\mathbb{R}^k\times 0^{n-k}$ with a $2$-homogeneous function.

I am interested in whether the following "global" analogue of (3) holds.

> Let $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Morse-Bott function and $C$ be its connected critical submanifold.
> Is that true that then there exists a regular neighborhood $q:E \to C$ of $C$ in $M$ such that $f \circ q: E \to \mathbb{R}$ coincides near $C$ with some $2$-homogeneous function $g:E \to \mathbb{R}$?

I will be grateful for any information about that problem.

Comment: You can state (2) as saying that the normal bundle to $C$ is a direct sum of two sub-bundles, call them the positive and negative sub-bundles. There is a Riemann metric in the tubular neighbourhood of $C$ such that $f$ is the distance squared (from $C$) of the projection to the positive sub-bundle minus the distance-squared (from $C$) of the projection to the negative sub-bundle.

Comment: Thank you Ryan. This might work. Then the next step is to properly glue all those Riemannian metrics.
- Suppose we can create such metric for the case when f is of index 0 i.e. it is a sum of squares.
- Then we can choose such metric independently on positive and negative bundles,
- Then together they might give a global Riemannian metric near C, and f will be still squared distance to C of coordinated on positive subbundle minus squared distance to C of coordinated on negative subbundle.